# Bookmark How to fetch all orders of last 12 hours only instead of all using Shopware 5 Order API?

Tags: shopware

How to fetch all orders of the last 12 hours only instead of all using Order API?

For example
   I am fetching all the orders like `https://domain/api/orders`
this will return all the orders, but I just want to fetch the last 12 hours orders, then how can I get it?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom api endpoint with the query from `Shopware\Components\Api\Resource\Order::getList()` just add where ordertime >= "curDate"

Comment: Thank you @jinnoflife, Yes I am able to pass the date that's fine, suppose I need to fetch only last 3 hours order then?

Comment: Okay, @jinnoflife, is there any other way you know, please let me know

Comment: @RonakSolanki I don't know any. But why don't you use this solution?

Comment: yes I used your solution, but i need to fetch the last 3 hours orders only.

Comment: @RonakSolanki then you should create a new action in your api endpoint where you change your query to `ordetime >=  "three hours ago"`

Comment: you mean to change the core API code of the Shopware ?

Comment: No! Just as I wrote: "you should **create a new** action in **your api endpoint**"

Comment: Okay, But I am not getting what you say for "Create new action", can you please explain